# How to return result to a calling activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I have an application A which calls the Activity of another application B using the following code.

```
    int request_code = 4;
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("name.of,packageB","class.name.of.packageB");
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(i, request_code);
```

Target activity in Application B is started and this Target Activity spawn out another service.

I need to return the result to the calling activity once this service finishes.

Is there any way to do this other than calling `sendBroadcast(Intent)`

I have the following code which is not working. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_main);

    String finish_activity="";
    try{
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent!=null && intent.getExtras()!=null)
        finish_activity = intent.getExtras().getString("finish_activity", "");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    if(finish_activity.equals("")){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
    startService(intent);
    } else{

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
        finish();
    }


}
```

I am calling this Activity again through the service to return the result which is not working.
Code of service calling my Target Activity.

```
    Intent intent_finish = new Intent(context, TargetActivityName.class);
    intent_finish.putExtra("finish_activity", "true");
    intent_finish.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent_finish.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
    intent_finish.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent_finish);
```

I am not receiving any callback for the startActivityForResult in my Application A. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Full code of my two application.
 Application A

```
public class AppA extends Activity {

private Button mOnBootBtn;
private Button mSettingsBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if((requestCode == 4 )&& (resultCode==RESULT_OK)){
        System.out.println("result code = "+requestCode);
    }
};

public void simulate(View view){
    if(view.getId() == R.id.invoke){
            int request_code = 4;
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.example.AppB","com.example.AppB.Test");
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivityForResult(i, request_code);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
    }
```

Application B - Test.java

```
public class Test extends Activity {

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_main);

String finish_activity="";
try{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent!=null && intent.getExtras()!=null)
    finish_activity = intent.getExtras().getString("finish_activity", "");
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
if(finish_activity.equals("")){
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startService(intent);
} else{

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
    finish();
}


}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}


}
```

Application B- Service.java

```
public class Service extends Service {
public static Context context;
public static Intent receivedIntent;
public static String calling_intent;

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent1, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent1, startId);
    System.out.println("Inside Service");
    if (NetworkAvailable(context)) {


            Intent intent_finish = new Intent(context, Test.class);
            intent_finish.putExtra("finish_activity", "true");
            intent_finish.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent_finish.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
            intent_finish.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            startActivity(intent_finish);
    }

    }else{
        System.out.println("Inside service - No net");
    }


}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent receivedIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;

}


private static boolean NetworkAvailable(Context context) {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
try{
connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    return false;
}


}


}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to override your calling activity's method of: onActivityResult(). More can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html "Android documentation for activity result")

Comment: @Stunna: I have onActivityResult() in my Application A. I'm not getting a call back to this. When I debug the application after the Target application finishes, I am expecting control to be transferred to Application A but Application A doesn't get control back. I think the service that is calling the Target activity is getting the call back. My doubt is how to give this result back to the originally called application A

Comment: I'm sorry, but since I don't see your code, I just want to make sure that you also did include @Override above your implementation of onActivityResult? Any way to post your implementation of your method?

Comment: @Stunna I've added the complete code. Please help me with where I am going wrong.

Comment: Has my answer helped?

Comment: @Stunna No. But thanks for your efforts. I solved it by killing the app completely using `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`. I was manually testing the app and discovered that result was sent when i force closed the app. finish() was not actually finishing the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised that your compiler isn't complaining about that extra semi-colon. But you are missing your @Override on your method. Your entire method signature should look like:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if((requestCode == 4 )&& (resultCode==RESULT_OK)){
            System.out.println("result code = "+requestCode);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` prevents the caller from receiving results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).